# How can I detect if my code should Impersonate or not?

Tags: tridion

I have code that runs as part of an event handler and need to create a new TOM.NET session (I can't reuse `subject.Session`). This event handler is loaded into many Tridion processes (TcmServiceHost, COM+, Publisher, TcmTemplateDebugHost, IIS Application Pool) and these processes may:

- run under an identity that has access to Tridion (e.g. the COM+ application runs under MTSUser, which is a Tridion administrator)
- run under an identity that doesn't have access to Tridion, but is allowed to impersonate Tridion users (e.g. TcmServiceHost runs as NetworkService, which is configured as a Tridion Impersonation User).

I try to cater for both cases with this TOM.NET code:

```
Session session = null;
try
{
    session = new Session();
}
catch (AccessDeniedException ex)
{
    // this process doesn't have TCM access, so impersonate a user that does
    session = new Session("Administator");
}
if (session != null)
{
    var item = session.GetObject(id);
    ...
```

Is this the right way to check whether my code is running under a process that has access to Tridion (ignoring the fact that I hard-coded "Administrator")? The code works, but I just wonder if there is a more efficient way to perform a "has access to Tridion" check?

**Note**: the same question arises when I use the Core Service to access Tridion, so the question is not whether the TOM.NET is the right API to use here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not use this code. Exception catching is slow and you are currently giving (Administrator) access to anyone who cannot access the system - which is a big security hole to have.

Instead, I would look at who the current user is and figure out if he is an impersonation user or not. You could read the impersonation users from the Tridion.ContentManager.config file directly, if there isn't an API for it (I haven't checked).

```
var isImpersonationUser = IsImpersonationUser(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
var session = isImpersonationUser ? new Session("Administrator") : new Session();
var item = session.GetObject(id);
```

Or you would have it be configurable separately for your event code. Or even hard-coded, if you don't care about the code being generic.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Reading the impersonation users from the TCM configuration is a great idea. I gave it a spin today and that seems to work.

Comment: No Peter, he is not giving Admin access to "anyone who cannot access the system", but rather to the identities that are not Tridion trustees, but /are/ impersonation users. This difference is crucial: an impersonation user is expected to be able to impersonate any trustee, including admins.

Comment: If you do want to read the impersonation users from the config, I would assume that getting this data from the memory cache is better than direct file access, so using the configuration API would be better, at least for an "internal" like Puf who won't have any doubts over support.

Comment: @DominicCronin true, the system will not allow you to impersonate if you aren't an impersonation user. So the security impact is less than I initially thought. 

But the code is still undesirable in my opinion. For instance, what if the user  has access to the system but not any of the Publications. 

In essence, the code doesn't match his intentions and it's going to be difficult for someone else to read the code and understand exactly what it is trying to do.

Comment: @PeterKjaer Yes - I agree with you there. I've written an answer describing my view more fully

Comment: Hey Peter, checking if the current user is an impersonation user works indeed and cleans up the code very nicely. Do you mind if I add the code to your answer?

Answer (score 2):

This code seems pretty efficient to me - but by checking if you can create the session object will by no means guarantee that the code will be able to perform the action you want to actually carry out in the CMS.

It also seems like such code is creating a large security vulnerability allowing processes to fallback to a higher level of security when they don't have permissions. Also keep in mind that if you are modifying any items in the CMS, that impersonation will have the result of not showing the real name of the individual which may have triggered the change. It will be stored as the user you are impersonating.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I already feared there wouldn't be a better mechanism. :-/ 

The event handler makes no modifications to any data in the content manager, but does need read-only access to a potentially large set of system content. It is quite common to require a configurable "administrator" user for such cases. It indeed requires my code to take care that it doesn't let any information escape that the user normally won't have access to. Don't worry, it doesn't. :-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is a great question/topic.

I think that you are trying to "build" something generic that can work on every Tridion process. In my opinion, you should know when you are in one process or another, since, based on the Best Practices (R&D/you) we shouldn't be creating Session objects, but use the Core Service in those processes that doesn't have access to the Session object and reuse the available session when possible.

As you know in Templating and Event System, for example, we have access to the Session, so we should be reusing it (unless we want to do stuff the user is not allowed to do, in which case we should impersonate).

If in another process the session is not available you should use Core Service.

So my answer to your question is not to use TOM.NET. I would change my approach and build it using the Core Service, where I can impersonate with an specific user that I have already configured previously. And your code would be more generic and would run "everywhere" (not in a toaster, though).

I understand what you are trying to identify here, "who the heck is running my current process"? so you can impersonate accordingly,

Unfortunately (AFAIK) you would have to write some code to see who is the identity running the process and then impersonate accordingly. This is tricky, and that's, again,  why I would recommend to use the Core Service instead of the TOM.NET API.

Hope this make sense.

Comment: I have the exact same implementing using both the TOM.NET and the Core Service. But the Core Service variant has the same problem (if-fail-then-imersonate) and is a lot more verbose. That is why I chose to post the TOM.NET version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Back when the TDSE.Impersonate() method was originally implemented, it was consciously designed to fail silently if the invoking thread identity was not an impersonation user. This allowed, for example, the ASP code in the GUI of the day to blindly attempt impersonation (based on the REMOTE_USER header IIRC). The point was that if you weren't an impersonation user, OK, fine, you could just be yourself, but if you were, you could/would impersonate.

I just tested this with the COM API (I'll leave it to you to verify that the .NET API is consistent). My results (on Tridion 2011 SP1) are as follows:

1). An impersonation user that is a trustee and does not impersonate becomes himself.
2). An impersonation user that is a trustee and impersonates, becomes whoever they impersonate (N.B. You would usually prefer not to create such a user). 
3). A non-impersonation user who calls impersonate remains himself.

Obviously, a lot hinges on whether the process identity is an impersonation user. Perhaps there are scenarios where you may prefer to avoid using NETWORK SERVICE and explicitly create an idenity for TcmServiceHost, simply to allow fine-grained control over whether such a user may impersonate.

So... should you need to explicitly test for whether your process is running as an impersonator? It may be better to simply attempt the impersonation, and accept the result. The original thinking certainly included this intention, but I suspect things have since become more complex.

+1 for the question, because it's utterly essential that there is no doubt as to expected behaviour in this area.

Comment: Impersonation no longer fails silently.

Comment: Then a lot depends on how precisely targeted the exception is.

Comment: I've had a bit of a poke around, and it looks like you get an AccessDeniedException for pretty much everything